# SQL Pivot 3 columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Sample data below, I need to pivot this data and turn Num Column into, NUM1, NUM2, NUM3, NUM4, etc. up to NUM12 and In Ascending order. This seemed easy at first. Data comes from a View generating this, in the back end, NUM is N1-N12 but not in order, and If i can reorder the columns by value that would work too

```
            ID | NUM |  Label         |GEN_ID | TimeStamp
            4   |1| 12/18/2017 part 1   |4| 2017-12-18
            4   |2| 12/18/2017 part 1   |4| 2017-12-18
            4   3   12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   4   12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   5   12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   7   12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   10  12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   11  12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   18  12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   20  12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   21  12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            4   22  12/18/2017 part 1   4   2017-12-18
            7   1   12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   2   12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   7   12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   8   12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   11  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   12  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   13  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   14  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   16  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   17  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   19  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            7   22  12/18/2017 part 1   7   2017-12-18
            8   1   12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   2   12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   15  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   16  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   17  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   18  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   19  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   20  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   21  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   22  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   23  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            8   24  12/18/2017 part 1   8   2017-12-18
            9   1   12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   2   12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   6   12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   10  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   11  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   13  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   15  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   16  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   19  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   20  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   22  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
            9   23  12/18/2017 part 1   9   2017-12-18
```

Comment: Please show how the desired output should look for the input data that you provided.

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: please post:
1) Queries to CREATE your table(s) including indexes 
2) Queries  to INSERT sample data. 
3) The desired result given the sample, as text or image of excel for example. 
4) A short description of the business rules, and how you got 1-2 of the results 
5) Which version of SQL Server you are using (this will help to fit the query to your version).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure desired output but this should get you in right direction:

```
SELECT ROWID,
LABEL,
GEN_ID,
[1] AS NUM1,
[2] AS NUM2,
[3] AS NUM3,
[4] AS NUM4,
[5] AS NUM5,
[6] AS NUM6,
[7] AS NUM7,
[8] AS NUM8,
[9] AS NUM9,
[10] AS NUM10,
[11] AS NUM11,
[12] AS NUM12
  FROM (
SELECT ID AS ROWID,NUM,LABEL,GEN_ID FROM [table] )AS S
PIVOT (MAX(NUM) FOR NUM IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) AS PT
```

[Rextester](http://rextester.com/YHHLX63599)